# Determining the roughness of a multidimensional optimization surface

Tags: optimization, fractals, chaos-theory

Is there a way to determine the roughness of an n-dimensional optimization surface (n > 3)? 
Preferably a method that uses measures from fractal geometry/chaos theory...